# Surface RT signs out user immediately

Tags: windows-8.1, login, microsoft-surface, login-screen

I have an administrator account and a normal user on my Surface RT (first generation), running Windows 8.1. I can log into the administrator account just fine...

However, whenever I log into the standard user account, it instantly goes to a "signing out" screen and returns to the login screen. I have tried using my password, pin, and picture password, and the same thing happens for all three.

I also tried to refresh the OS, but it asks for a Bitlocker recovery key*, which I definitely don't have. (I tried running chkdsk to see if that would fix that problem, but to no avail.)

* *Error messages: "Enter the recovery key to get going again." When I press "Skip this drive": "The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again."*

Comment: Try creating a new user, this will allow you to backup your personal files, then perform a factory reset.  If you don't have the recovery key we can't help.

Comment: As mentioned, the admin user account works; so I can back up files. I would have preferred not to do a full hard drive reset though.

Comment: But I don't understand why it's asking for a recovery key. I never locked the drive. I've never even used Bitlocker. I never set a recovery key, and I was never given a recovery key with the Surface (to my knowledge). I did buy it refurbished so maybe it's possible someone else did.